# Basic JavaScript - Fibonacci Sequence Generator Not Working

Tags: javascript

I am new to JavaScript, for some reason my Fibonacci Sequence Generator. What is a Fibonacci Sequence, easy, it is a sequence that takes the last two numbers of the sequence and adds them to create the next number. Here is an example. 0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21... I tried to make a loop with a while statement in which the variable that was once the first number (in this case 0), converts into a new number which is whatever that number was plus the second number (in this case 1). example: var firstNumber(which is 0) + var secondNumber(which is 1) = var firstNumber(which no equals to 1 because we added 0 + 1). If this goes on in a loop, then, in theory, it could go infinitely adding the last number and the one before it, and making that second to last number making the result of the addition. Here is my code, it is not working at all. Any help would be deeply appreciated. Hopefully, I have explained my self correctly.

```js
var firstNumber = 0;
var secondNumber = 1;

function fibonacciGenerator(n){
    while (secondNumber <= n){
        firstNumber + secondNumber == firstNumber;
        secondNumber + firstNumber == secondNumber;
    }
}
console.log(fibonacciGenerator(50));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`firstNumber + secondNumber == firstNumber;` this is not the way to assign a value to a variable

and you need to add a return statement at the end of your function.

Does this help ?

```js
var firstNumber = 0;
var secondNumber = 1;

function fibonacciGenerator(n){
  while (secondNumber <= n){
      firstNumber = firstNumber + secondNumber;
      secondNumber = secondNumber + firstNumber;
  }
  return secondNumber
}

console.log(fibonacciGenerator(50));
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for stepping out of your way to help me. Unfortunately, I am not very experienced in this language yet. This is what I did after reading your question and it didn't work. Did I do something wrong? 

I only changed the last row.

return console.log(fibonacciGenerator(50));

Comment: Thank you! it works perfectly on this page (stack overflow) when I hit run, but I get nothing on the chrome console or in any other code playground page, why is that? you know?

Comment: it is working in codepen check this link: https://codepen.io/am-77/pen/LYpgNze

Comment: it looks that the algorithm not implemented correctly because **Fibonacci** of **50** equal `12586269025` not `89`

Comment: @Joseph thanks for pointing that out but it is not what I need. The 50 does not represent the Fibonacci of 50, which yes, equals what you said. the 50 in this code represents the highest number the generator should reach so that it does not run forever.

Comment: Yes, it works, I did a hard refresh on my chrome browser, I don't know what happened. Thanks, @Pain.

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign a third variable to store the sum of the first and second variable each iteration after that you should make your loop starts from **2**, not **1** because you already assing it before the loop staring,
another thing when you assign a value from variable to another it works from right side to left side so it should be like this

```
 firstNumber = firstNumber + secondNumber;
 secondNumber = secondNumber + firstNumber;
```

so after editing it would be like this

```js
function fibonacciGenerator(n) {
    var a = 0,
        b = 1,
        c;

    for (let i = 2; i <= n; i++) {
        c = a + b;
        a = b;
        b = c;
    }

    return b;
}
console.log(fibonacciGenerator(9))
```

to read more about it check this [link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/program-for-nth-fibonacci-number/)

Comment: That is a very smart and different way to reaching the result I needed. Thank you @Joseph! I did not think about that.